# Two Laptops Connected to One Monitor; KVM Not Working With Both Setups

Tags: networking, kvm-switch

I would like to connect my Macbook Air and HP Laptop to the same monitor.

The HP laptop & KVM are connected to a docking station. Both laptops are connected to the monitor via HDMI (thunderbolt 2 adapter used with the Macbook). I am able to switch between the laptop display inputs, but cant get the KVM to work with the Macbook setup... I did some research on KVM switches, but don't have a clear answer if it will be compatible with both laptops. Is there any way to use the dock as a KVM switch? KVM are connected via USB-- I do not want have wireless. Would prefer not to spend more money on this if possible.

Comment: The whole idea of questioning whether a KVM is compatible with a laptop, is bizarre when you have the KVM.  Like what do you mean "not compatible"!

Comment: You write "use the dock as a KVM switch" <-- what on earth are you talking about?  a docking station? a docking station is not a KVM switch obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Some KVMs are finicky about their connections.  If you have the HP on wire set A and the Mac on wire set B, try switching them around - Mac on A and HP on B. Or possibly plugging the USB into the computer instead of a dock. One weird KVM I had wanted one of the machines fully powered on before booting the other. And just to mention, I had some USB KVMs that just absolutely would not work when trying to connect different brands of computers. Good luck.